# why I cant send a message from shared mailbox, even after removing the addin

Tags: javascript, outlook, office365, outlook-web-addins, outlook-web-app

I'm working on owa addin with on-send functionality enabled, I got this `Load add-ins that are required for your organization` when sending a message from shared mailbox account, I disabled and removed the add-in but still got the same thing, any how can I send email from shared mailbox in that case?

Comment: Can you explain more on the issue and how you fixed the same ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was the on-send functionality that blocks the sending, removing it from the delegated account will make it able to send message, even if the add-in is installed/enabled